# How to vertical-align image link in heading h2 to bottom?

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

Currently I just want a image link in a h2.

This link should be positioned bottom.

This is what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            h2 {
                margin: 5px 0 10px;
                background: #333333;
                color: #f7f7f7;
                line-height: 142%;
            }
            h2 a {
                float: right;
            }
            h2 img {
                vertical-align: bottom;
            }
            h2:after {
                content:"";
                height: 1px;
                display: block;
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Header <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/26x26" /></a></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the strange thing is, that when I include this code in a .html file. I have an `<a>` tag of 26px height.

When I create a jsfiddle, the `<a>` tag is 34px and aligned bottom?!?!

[HTML file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3261523/test.html)

[jsfiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/hZefD/embedded/result/)

So, what is my mistake? I just want the image aligned at bottom...

Comment: You have no `doctype`, so the page will be rendered in quirks mode, also JSFiddle adds in a `normalize.css` stylesheet, which is similar to a `reset stylesheet`

Comment: @NickR It's not active by default, you need to go into fiddle options and turn on normalize.css

Comment: @YaMo Ah Ok, too bad I can't edit that now :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a doctype before the html tag:

> `<!DOCTYPE html>`